# Image encodeing/decoding in javascript/html5

Tags: javascript, html

I had a code snippet in a web-application which used to take a snapshot or upload an image file from the client device and it used to work perfect! I also had succeeded to resize the picture "on the fly". Suddendly a few days afo it stopped working. Does anyone know if there is a recent update in browsers that could cause this?
I am giving the javasctipt and the html part that used to do the work..

HTML

```
...
  <div style="text-align: center;">
                <label class="cameraButton">
                    <input type="file" id="camera" onchange="previewFile();" capture="camera" accept="image/*;capture=camera">
                    <img src="images/click_to_shoot.png" id="Image1" runat="server" class="newpic" alt="" style="margin-top: 20px; width: 50%; height: auto; border: 1px solid;" />
                </label>
            </div>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hfLocalStorage" Value="@" runat="server" />
            <canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="600" style="border: 1px solid #d3d3d3; background-color: lightgray; display: none;"></canvas>
...
```

JS:

```
 function previewFile() {
            var preview = document.getElementsByClassName('newpic')[0];
            var file = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
                var rr = reader.result.replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '');
                preview.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + rr;
                document.getElementById('<%=hfLocalStorage.ClientID%>').value = rr;
                var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
                var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
                var img = preview;
                var wrh = img.width / img.height;
                var newWidth = c.width;
                var newHeight = newWidth / wrh;
                if (newHeight > c.height) {
                    newHeight = c.height;
                    newWidth = newHeight * wrh;
                }
                var startx = (c.width - newWidth) / 2;
                var starty = (c.height - newHeight) / 2;
                ctx.drawImage(img, startx, starty, newWidth, newHeight);
                makeproper();
            }, false);
            if (file) {
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            }
        }
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Does it throw any errors?

Comment: I think it’s more likely this is caused by a server update or misconfiguration rather than browser updates. Does it run on other servers?

Comment: Thank you agrm! I think that this is possible but I also get the same result running on localhost on my pc. (In Visual Studio 2013). It doesnt throw any errors but just doesn't re-encode the image proper. (Just a transparent canvas)

Comment: You are creating a Image but don't wait for it to finish loading

Comment: Also i would do: `rr = reader.result.split(',')[1]` since the image might not always be jpeg, could be png or webp

Comment: Thank you so much Endless!! Indeed, I put a small delay (0.5 sec) between the creation of the image and the painting of the canvas and it worked fine! I will also consider following you advice about splitting the reader result